# Explanation of lines of code

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

Can someone explain to me what he was doing only this one line of code?

```
.build();
```

from

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                                 this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
         .addApi(Drive.API)
         .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
         .setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
         .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

He completes the process of creating a GoogleApiClient obect using a the [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. You can then use the GoogleApiClient to complete whatever calls you need to make

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of the Builder Pattern.

The idea is to set an object fields (representation) dynamically, when done setting these fields you call the build method in order to get the instance you defined.

This pattern encapsulates the inner implementation while exposing the construction process.

you can read more about it here
[wiki page on builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

quick reference from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder

> build() Builds a new GoogleApiClient object for communicating with the
>   Google APIs.

Everything before the .build was preparation to create client and build actually build it and as this point the object of GoogleApiClient created in memory.